# Send auto-reply in outlook once message is manually moved to a specified folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to utilize outlook rules or add an extension to outlook that would allow me to send auto replies to emails once I manually move them to a folder in my outlook?

The scenario is as follows: I will be receiving inquiries and feedback from customers on my email, once I receive them I will manually move these emails to the Help Line folder after that I want an automated reply to be sent saying that we received your issue and we will be working on it. 
I do not know the email addresses nor the subject they will be writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my tests,  I' afraid that we could not ahcieve this requirement by Outlook rules alone.